# Laravel - Multiple Where Queries

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sqlite

I'm trying to use multiple where queries on a sqlite database which are then only selected between two date ssDate and seDate. for some reason, I am having nothing returned when I know there is an entry in between two dates.

```
        if($status == "newOngoingClosed"){
        //dd($status, $ssDate, $seDate);
        $selStatus = Account::where('cActive', '=', 'New')
        ->orWhere('cActive', '=', 'Ongoing')
        ->orWhere('cActive', '=', 'Closed')
        ->whereBetween ('refDate', [$ssDate, $seDate])
        ->get();
        dd($selStatus);
        return view('reports_active')->withDetails($selStatus)->withQuery($status);
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah the correct data is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query currently is:

```
select * 
from `accounts` 
where `cActive` = ? or `cActive` = ? or `cActive` = ? and `refDate` between ? and ?
```

Notice that the last condition is and AND which means it will select things which are either new or ongoing or closed **and** between those dates

You need:

```
Account::where([
      ['cActive', '=', 'New','or'] , 
      [ 'cActive', '=', 'Ongoing','or' ], 
      ['cActive', '=', 'Closed','or']
 ])->whereBetween ('refDate', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()])->get() //Note the carbons are just date placeholders , you can use your own
```

This will execute:

```
select * from `accounts` where (`cActive` = ? or `cActive` = ? or `cActive` = ?) and `refDate` between ? and ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using multiple `orWhere` you can use `whereIn` to get the desired output:

```
$selStatus = Account::whereIn('cActive', ['New','Ongoing','Closed'])
        ->whereBetween ('refDate', [$ssDate, $seDate])
        ->get();
```